# Outputting XML from MySQL & PHP (PDO)

Tags: php, xml

I am using PHP/PDO to query my MySQL table and return all records as formatted XML.

I -am- getting my output.. but its not exactly what I was expecting so am here to ask if this is normal? or (more likely) what I'm doing wrong.

This PHP script will be utilizedby another (existing) project that is Adobe Flash based.  (It is currently using a flat .xml file to load from.... I have been working on the first step(s) of up-grading this project (to eventually move away from Flash) so it pulls its data/xml feed from a database.

When I load the .php script directly in my browser.... I see all the 'values' printed on the screen (no XML tags).  However if i look at the pages source code, the XML tags -are- present/there.  (I'm using FireFox)..but there is syntax highlighting applied (default I guess for FireFox to have colored highlighting for source code?)..

anyways.. I mention it because I have one tag that is red and its matching (closing) tag is normal colored? leading me to believe I have some sort of error going on?

example of the XML source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saberFonts>
<entry submissionDate="2013-02-18 00:00:00">
    <fontName>Episode I QGJ </fontName>
    <fontCreator>Novastar</fontCreator>
    <fontFormat>.wav</fontFormat>
    <optimized>Plecter</optimized>
    <fontPrice>6.50</fontPrice>
    <fontImage>wav_cf.png</fontImage>
    <fontURL><![CDATA[https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&i=NS-EPIQGJ_PLECTER-.wav&cl=174914&ejc=2]]></fontURL>
    <description><![CDATA[An EPI QGJ font]]></description>
    <piracyVid></piracyVid>
    <demoLink height="315" width="420" title="">http://www.youtube.com/v/3IbzyyHo0o4?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0</demoLink>
    </entry>

etc..etc..etc (more entry nodes, same structure)..

</saberFonts>
```

The very first  tag/node name is RED in the source, where the closing is normal black/purple??

Question 1: is this normal? seeing values printed on screen?  without any XML tags/structure?  (and XML structure only in source?)

Question 2: and the syntax highlighting 'issues'? why would 1 tag be RED and the other be normal? all my CDATA values are in RED.. but the first/opening  tag?

Here is my code I am using to query and build my XML 'string' output.

```
<?php
session_start();

$host_name = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'test';
$user_name = 'root';
$password = '';

$table = 'fontentries';

try {
    $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$db_name", $user_name , $password);
    //$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection -not- made<br/>';
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$getAll_query = "SELECT * FROM `fontentries` WHERE active != 0;";
$xml_statement = $conn->prepare($getAll_query);
$xml_statement->execute();

$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
$xml_output .= "<saberFonts>\n"; 

foreach ($xml_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    //get/set $row data
    $fontID=$row['id'];
    $date_entered=$row["date_entered"];
    $font_name=$row["font_name"];
    $font_maker=$row["font_maker"];
    $font_format = $row["font_format"];
    $optimized_for= $row["optimized_for"];  
    $font_price=$row["font_price"];
    $font_image = $row["font_image"];
    $font_url=$row["font_url"];
    $description=$row["description"];
    $youtube_id=$row["youtube_id"];
    $ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $active = $row["active"];
    $custom_config = $row['custom_config'];
    $led_txt = $row['led_txt']; 

    $xml_output .= "\t<entry submissionDate=\"".$date_entered."\">\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<fontName>" . $font_name . "</fontName>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<fontCreator>" . $font_maker . "</fontCreator>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<fontFormat>" . $font_format . "</fontFormat>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<optimized>" . $optimized_for . "</optimized>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<fontPrice>" . $font_price . "</fontPrice>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<fontImage>" . $font_image . "</fontImage>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<fontURL><![CDATA[https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&i=" . $font_url . "&cl=174914&ejc=2]]></fontURL>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<description><![CDATA[" . $description . "]]></description>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<piracyVid></piracyVid>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<demoLink height=\"315\" width=\"420\" title=\"\">http://www.youtube.com/v/" . $youtube_id . "?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0</demoLink>\n";

    $xml_output .= "\t</entry>\n";  
}

$xml_output .= "</saberFonts>";  
echo $xml_output;

?>
```

At this point, I'm not sure why I'm getting these results? Figured I'd post here to get some help/answers from those who has more experience.

thanks!

Comment: I highly recommend you build your XML document using an actual XML library like DOM or SimpleXML.

Comment: Thanks!  However, if I knew how,.. I wouldnt be posting. ;)  I appreciate the 'comment' though.

Answer (score 2):

Building XML documents manually via string concatenation is only going to lead to difficulty. I recommend you use an XML library like [DOM](http://php.net/manual/book.dom.php).

Here's how I would do it.

```
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM fontentries WHERE active <> 0');
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$fonts = $doc->createElement('sabreFonts');

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $entry = $doc->createElement('entry');
    $entry->setAttribute('submissionDate', $row['date_entered']);

    $entry->appendChild($doc->createElement('fontName', $row['font_name']));
    $entry->appendChild($doc->createElement('fontCreator', $row['font_maker']));

    // and so on

    // CDATA sections are slightly different
    $description = $doc->createElement('description');
    $description->appendChild($doc->createCDATASection($row['description']));
    $entry->appendChild($description);

    $fonts->appendChild($entry);
}

$doc->appendChild($fonts);

// Set the appropriate content-type header and output the XML
header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo $doc->saveXML();
exit;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I didnt get an email notification (otherwise I would have responded sooner)..

from you previous comment I started to search simpleXML,..and found a very simple fix that should fit well into my already established code.  

I tried it, but I am now getting another error (parsing the data error)... I believe this stems from having special characters in some of the fields in the database.  (such as & and apostrophes..and any others as well)

I believe I need to 'take care of this' when I'm declaring the variable/record data in the for()loop..  but what should I use?

Comment: I used: htmlspecialchars() and it got past the parsing error.. 

this was the thread I had followed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458603/exporting-data-from-mysql-in-the-xml-using-php

but in the end it leaves me in the same spot, just the values (no XML markup) displayed on the screen..The source code -does- show the XML formatted data though.

Your DOM example is great! (by the way) very easy to understand/follow (even for me!)  haha

I'm going to seek out a simpleXML way to (correctly) build an XML object... if I cant fond or figure it out though, I'll use your DOM example! thanks

Comment: @whispers Why would you expect the browser to display an XML document any differently? You should only be concerned with how your client (flash app) consumes the data.

Comment: @Phil-

I just recall seeing 'XML feeds' that were PHP scripts that when I loaded them in the browsers directly.. looked like a nicely formatted XML document (with little + / - signs for nested child nodes/elements..etc)

Having only ever created an XML feed using this sctring approach I was curious to try it (reading that other thread I thought it would lead to that and was a 'quick fix' to my already existing code.

As far as Flash goes.. from what I recall, I believe it will work as is. I havent cracked open the app in a long time.. (or done any flash development in a while)